# WebApplicationFactory unable to set initial data for tests in InMemoryDatabase

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I'm trying to perform some test using everything from my application.
My idea is to use WebApplicationFactory and change the database context of ECSContext which is used during the tests to point to an in memory database with dummy data.
Here is part of my code:

```
class MyWebApplication : WebApplicationFactory<Program> {
    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder) {
        IHost host = base.CreateHost(builder);
        return host;
    }
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder) {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services => {
            services.RemoveAll<DbContextOptions<ECSContext>>();

            services.AddDbContext<ECSContext>(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            });
            using(var scope = services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope()) {
                var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ECSContext>();
                dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();
                dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
                dbContext.TUsers.AddRange(TestDataProvider.GetSampleUsers());
                dbContext.TRoles.AddRange(TestDataProvider.GetSampleRoles());
                dbContext.TUsersroles.AddRange(TestDataProvider.GetSampleUsersAndRoles());
                int changesMade = dbContext.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine($"ChangesMade: {changesMade}");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This seems to partially work, however, the data that I'm adding is not persisting.
I did this for initialization:

```
namespace UnitTests_EternalCODEStudio_API.TestData2 {
    public class BaseTestInitialziacion {
        protected string baseURLString = "https://localhost:7228/";
        MyWebApplication WebApp = null!;
        protected HttpClient httpClient = null!;
        [TestInitialize] // Set up common objects for tests
        public void Setup() {
            WebApp = new MyWebApplication();
            httpClient = WebApp.CreateClient();
        }
    }
}
```

Which is then passed to my tests:

```
namespace UnitTests_EternalCODEStudio_API.Controllers.UserController {
    [TestClass] // Mark the class as a test class
    public class UnitTest_UserController_LoginToken : BaseTestInitialziacion {
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task Test_UserController_Login_OK() {
            // Act
            UsersDTO_usernameAndPass userData = new UsersDTO_usernameAndPass {
                Username = "user1",
                Password = "Test!Password1"
            };
            StringContent jsonContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            // Act
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{baseURLString}Users/Login", jsonContent);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        }
```

However, when debugging the Users/Login endpoint being called, the context.TUsers shows that there is no data.
How is this possible?
What I'm doing wrong and why is the data not being saved to the in memory database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the duplicate. Move `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` to variable outside of the `AddDbContext` call.

Comment: Also I highly recommend to never build service multiple times (i.e. calling `services.BuildServiceProvider()` when using hosting for example).

Comment: @GuruStron Thank you! It worked :D
You can't imagine how many hours I've been searching for a solution.